# HTML: show abbreviated text; let full text be copied to clipboard

Tags: html

I'm trying to achieve the following effect in a dynamic web page:

- The quick brown [...] lazy dogs.

When the user hovers over any of this text, they see the full sentence. The ... is some sort of link-like element such that when the user right clicks on it, they can copy the full text: "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs." goes into the clipboard.

For now, I kludged it using `mailto:`. That is to say:

```
<span title="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.">
  The quick brown
  [<a href="mailto:The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.">...</a>]
  lazy dogs.
</span>
```

With the above, the functionality is **exactly right**, except that the browser's context menu says "Copy E-Mail Address", which the text isn't. If the menu item said "Copy Full Text" it would be perfect.

I tried using a `data:` URL (inline data), but Firefox's context menu refers to it as Copy Link Location (it isn't a location) and doesn't strip the `data:` prefix as it does the `mailto:` prefix!

I don't want to pollute the code with some complicated thing in Javascript just for this.

Comment: What if than suddenly you have this text: `Mom is cool.` >> where should the clipboard link appear? (UI mistake?)

Comment: P.S: you better *"pollute"* your UI with some useful JS than using invalidly `mailto:`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  The code which generates the markup only generates this abbreviation for long texts. `Mom is cool.` is too short. You don't get the clipboard link in this case; you just have to copy and paste manually. Alternatively, you can click on the [Edit] link for that text (not shown in the question) and copy it out of the text box, then back-button to the page.